# Currency symbol is displyed at right side of the product price.How to bring it to the left of the price?

Tags: magento2

Currency symbol is displyed at right side of the product price.How to bring it to the left of the price?

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {    
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();    
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);  
        return $this;
    } 

<event name="currency_display_options_forming">
<observer name="change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Products\Plugin\Locale\Currency" />
</event>
```

Above code is not working